# Python equivalent to R 's factor data type

Tags: python, r, python-2.7, scipy, scikit-learn

I'm new in using Python as scientific language.

I'm missing using an data type that informs me the data it self and the factors the data are in. (Specially for categorical data array. )

I'm wondering if there's a **lib** or **an array** type in `scipy package` for this usage ?

Comment: The r analogue is pandas (is my understanding) and it has a categorical data type: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html

Comment: @Frank thanks !! That's pretty much what I'm looking for. !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try pandas

http://pandas.pydata.org/

and take a look at:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html

It's an amazing library that does pretty what what you're asking for.